# use common jsp in all other pages

Tags: jsp, jstl

i want add a common page head.jsp in all other page, in any directory

on some pages, this code works

```
<c:import url="common/head.jsp" ></c:import>
```

and, on the other pages, this code

```
<c:import url="<c:url value='/common/head.jsp' />" ></c:import>
```

However, none of the codes do not work on all pages

Comment: relative path changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Tiles API to get the required template.

Visit http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/basic/pages.html for more details